# How to use text file as local database

Tags: c++

I have a data_base.txt file with the next structure:

```
1|client_name|id_client|account_client|balance|status
2|client_name|id_client|account_client|balance|status
```

Example:

```
1|John Doe|08913835P|053-323-192|120.00|active
```

Now I want to have the next four functions working with this file:

This function will add a new client to the .txt file

```
int newClient(string client_name, string id_client)
{
  .....
}
```

This function will check if a client exists by checking `id_client`

```
int checkClient(string id_client)
{
  // return true; (if client with that ID exists)
  // return false; (if client not exists)
}
```

This function will get a specific value:

```
int getData(string field, string id_client)
{
 // Example: if string field == 'balance' and id_client == '08913835P' then return '120.00'
 // This example is done using above example data structure.
}
```

This function will modify data

```
int modifyData(string field, string data)
{
 // This should work like the previous function but this function will edit specific values.
}
```

That's all, I had been Googling for hours and I can't figure out yet how to do this.

Comment: if the data length is not fixed, then as @Beta mentioned it is hardest, you might end up using a db because you can't append into the middle of the file

Comment: @Sleiman Jneidi I wouldn't like to use any database.. do you think I could do this with XML for example? thanks.

Comment: Probably the simplest way to update entries is to write the modifications to a new file as you read in the current file and swap the new file with the current one if the update succeeded. Otherwise you either end up with something horribly inefficient or you end up re-implementing a proper database with index files and metadata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is problematic and horribly inefficient if not done right.

The short answer is that, if the length of each line can change, then you need to completely rewrite the entire file to update the data. This would work, for example, if your program loaded the entire file into memory and then saved it after it was modified.

To update the file on disk, you have to impose some type of rule, such as every line must be the same length. This would mean setting a maximum length for all your fields, and padding those fields with spaces or some other character.

Using the latter technique, it should be possible to construct a new line of data (with padding), know the location of that line in the file (line number - 1 times the length of each line), jump to that location and then write the line.

Getting the data would be simpler but similar. Just determine the offset of the line and read it (you'll know how long the lines is). Strip any padding before presenting to the user.

Modifying a line would be similar to a combination of getting the data and writing the data. You'd just update the data between the two.